# setState draft js from enter key

Tags: javascript, draftjs

please help me.
I have a code like this, but there is a problem at the time of changing the state, the message error is 'Uncaught Error: Got unexpected null or undefined (...)'

```
var contentState, editorState, text;
text = this.state.text;
contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(Draft.convertFromHTML(text));
editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
this.setState({
  editorState: editorState
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.text`?

Comment: the value is `"<p>*598 *599 *600 </p>"`

Comment: i use jquery text complete, when i select the option in jquery text complete it take the id of option selected and put to state text, if i select the option with click from mouse it's no problem, but when i use enter key there's problem

Answer (score 0):

why not just copy codes from [doc](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#convertfromhtml)

```
const sampleMarkup =
  '<b>Bold text</b>, <i>Italic text</i><br/ ><br />' +
  '<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Example link</a><br /><br/ >' +
  '<img src="image.png" height="112" width="200" />';

const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
  blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
);

this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state),
};
```

Comment: yes I've tried it, but there is an error like this "Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'map' of undefined (...)"